# Sed-Replace immediate next string word coming after a particular pattern but only the first occurrence in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I need a `sed` command which will replace the string immediately after the pattern but only for the first occurrence in a file

For replacing first occurrence this was given:

```
sed -i '' -e '0,/abc/s//def/' filename
```

This will replace the matching string and not string after match

For replace string immediate after match this was given:

```
sed -i 's/\(text=\)\(.*\)/\1qwerty/' filename
```

This will replace string after immediate next to match but will do for all occurences.

In a file I have the string "text=abc" twice times like this:

```
abc
text=occurrence1
qwe
uio
text=occurrence2
dsf
```

I want to replace the `occurence1` part with  the string "qwerty" so that output looks like:

```
text=qwerty.
```

But I want to do this only for the first occurence in the file and not all places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
r="qwerty"

sed -i '' -e "1,/text=/s/\(text=\).*/\1${r}/" filename
```

This is as simple it can get.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed` should work:

Example:

```
cat file:
abc
text=xyz1
qwe
uio
text=xyz
dsf
```

Now, to replace only the first occurrence of string "text=" with "text=qwerty":

```
sed -r '0,/text=/{s/text=(.*)/text=qwerty/}' file
```

Output:

```
abc
text=qwerty
qwe
uio
text=xyz
dsf
```

Option '-r' in `sed`:

```
-r  : --regexp-extended, to use extended regular expressions
```

Comment: My situation is Anything might come after text= in the file. Thats why I gave text=occurence1, text=occurence2. I can only search the file with  "text=" string and not the whole line.

Comment: @RohithSriram: I've updated my answer, please check if this works now!!!